# True definition of a django app

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I'd like to know what the actual definition of a django app (application) is.

This question has been asked before, but it's still not clear to me what packages must be Django applications, and (crucially) listed as such in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`, and which packages can just be plain old python packages that are used in a generic python manner (i.e., simply imported in the usual python way without being listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`).

The closest answer I got was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18295329):

> Apps are generally oriented around models.

Answer (score 3):

There's a desciption of apps and projects [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/), but it doesn't include a definitive list of features that require the app to be included in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Here's my attempt at a list of features that require the app to be in `INSTALLED_APPS`, it's probably incomplete.

- models
- template tags
- a templates directory, if you want it to be found by the app directories loader
- code in an `AppConfig` class that you want to be run when the server starts